# Where to find pre-trained models for transfer learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, keras, transfer-learning

I am new to the machine learning field, but I wanted to try and implement a simple texture classification algorithm with Keras (to give a clear idea about what I mean as 'texture', [this][1] is the most basic texture database that can be found). However, I have a very small set of data, so I thought to try to apply transfer learning to the problem; however, I couldn't find anything on this online, so I wanted to understand which are the best places to look for a pre-trained neural network. Do you have any suggestion in this regard? Which website is best for getting an idea on how to start a machine learning project?